# Record sound from bluetooth speakers

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, bluetooth, speakers, audio-recording

I am using ffmpeg to record any sound playing on my system, using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Stereo Mix (Realtek High Definition Audio)" "<output_file_path>"
```

This is working as long as I set the output device to the laptop speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio). But is not working when the sound is being played on my external bluetooth speakers.

Is there any way to record whatever is being played by the bluetooth speakers, using ffmpeg or any other software?

I am using a Windows 10 64-bit on an Intel i5.

Comment: Did you try to change the audio device as your Bluetooth speakers are not connected through your on board sound card but (likely) rather an independent device?

Comment: I tried to list all the devices available, using `ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy`. Its only showing my webcam, microphone and sound card as the possible recording sources.

Comment: It could very well be that the BT device (driver) doesn't expose something similar to Stereo Mix. Even among sound cards it's not always available. You could look into something like [Voicemeeter](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm) or a simple virtual audio cable to work around this. Essentially you'd set your software/system to output to the virtual audio cable and let your system playback whatever is played on the virtual audio cable to some other source. It can be quite tricky setup and you have to figure out whenever the management is acceptable (changing outputs/inputs).

Comment: Wow, that sounds very interesting (no pun intended). Will try that. Thanks a lot @Seth.